# How to perform a performance benchmark testing of Google Dataproc, AWS-EMR and Azure HDInsights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-emr, google-cloud-dataproc, azure-hdinsight

I need to compare the performance of Azure HDInsights, AWS-EMR, and Google Dataprocs. Is there a way to do so or is there a third-party organization that has already done this?